# Modify contents of Welcome widget in Sonar

Tags: widget, sonarqube

I have included Welcome widget in my Sonar dashboard. Now I want to include my project specific documents and links in this widget.

I am not able to modify the default contents of this widget.
How can I update/delete contents of this welcome widget?

Answer (score 1):

You can only use `User Text Display` widget (available in [Widget Lab Plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Widget+Lab+Plugin)). It is associated with dashboard (not project) so all projects using this dashboard will see the same message.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @agabrys. I want to put some contents dynamically in Sonar dashboard. I like to put some hyper links (URL) and also want to display contents from email message body.